# Frontend javascript IE11 transpilation

Tags: javascript, node.js, internet-explorer-11, transpiler

There is a project with **node.js** backend and frontend consisting of **pug** views and **js** files. The problem is that lots of scripts don't work on **Internet Explorer 11**(*surprise*).

What is the fastest and the most simple solution to make them work?

Can it be solved only on build step(which is not needed yet in simple **node.js** project)?

Can it be made with pure **Babel**?

Should it be made with **webpack**?

Comment: are you targeting ES5? did you try adding some polyfills?

Comment: It seems ES5 would be okay for IE11 and it seems I have not tried polyfills

Comment: this could be the solution then!